# Zoom breaks in IE9 When using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, internet-explorer-9

I am using d3.js to zoom a svg. When tested in chrome, firefox, safari, it works greatly.

When tested in IE9, the zoom breaks and below is the error

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'transition'
File: d3.v3.min.js, Line: 5, Column: 8563
```

Any one know how to resolve this?

Comment: I can't say definitively, but IE9 and D3 don't get along, so I'm not surprised. If you run the code with the non-minified version (d3.v3.js) what line does it give the error at?

Comment: @Elijah will try and keep you updated! :)